# Router Child component is not binding

Tags: typescript, angular-ui-router, angular6

My router setup:

```
{
    path: "",
    component: DynamicContentComponent
  },
  { 
    path: ":ctype/:termid",   
    component: DynamicContentComponent,
    children: [    
      {

        path: "description/:nodeId" ,component: DescriptionContentComponent
      }
    ]
  }

];
```

My link matched with router(http://localhost:4200/restaurants/3025/description/2266) browser's address bar but the component is (i.e) `DescriptionContentComponent` is not loading,when on load it redirects to the `DynamicContentComponent`

Here,

> :ctype --> restaurants
>  :termid --> 3025 
> :nodeId --> 2266

Comment: Can you please show your code where you are adding the routing module to the imports and did you place the `<router-outlet>` tag in the parent component?

Answer (score 0):

Update your routes to this

```
{ 
    path: ":ctype/:termid",   
    component: DynamicContentComponent,
    children: [    
       {
         path: "description/:nodeId" ,component: DescriptionContentComponent
       }
     ]
},
{
    path: "",
    component: DynamicContentComponent
}
```

> The order of the routes in the configuration matters and this is by design. The router uses a first-match wins strategy when matching routes, so more specific routes should be placed above less specific routes. In the configuration above, routes with a static path are listed first, followed by an empty path route, that matches the default route. The wildcard route comes last because it matches every URL and should be selected only if no other routes are matched first.

Read more here: [Angular Routing](https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration)